# How to do 'prepareSegue' for back button?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've got a pretty simple question. In my app, there are some screens that have a navigation bar, and some that don't have it. So, what I did was to flag this manually between screen in `prepareForSegue:` using this line `self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true/false, animated: false)` . Now, how do I do it if I want to go back from a view controller with a navigation bar to a view controller that doesn't have it by clicking on the back button? I tried putting it in the `prepareForSegue:` of the child view controller but it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how you are maintaining your flags for hiding/unhiding the navigation Bar but you can use `UINavigationControllerDelegate` for the same

```
 @available(iOS 2.0, *)
    optional public func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool)

    @available(iOS 2.0, *)
    optional public func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool)
```

Alternatively, you can try to put `setNavigationBarHidden` in `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear` for each viewController.

Comment: Ah yeah, using `viewWillAppear` works. I tried `viewDidAppear` before, and it looked wrong because the navBar was showing / hiding when the whole screen has appeared. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

**you can also use a better approach with unwind segue**

```
override func didMoveToParentViewController(parent: UIViewController?) {
    if (parent == nil) {
        println("Back Button Pressed!")
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I'm using Swift 4.0 and the parent was never nil.